# Why is there no space between my URLs when page is loaded with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code for four `a` elements with Bootstrap's `btn` class on them.

```
<a href="{% url 'qna:answer-create-view' object.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Answer</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i> | 0</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down"></i> | 0</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Follow</a>
```

Normally there was a little space between them when I loaded them as an HTML page. However, I implemented `load()` function in my JS file and is now loading part of the page containing those elements so that it takes less time to load a new page. But in this method there are no spaces between those elements and it looks aesthetically unpleasant. How can I fix that?

Comment: Is the page you are loading that fragment into also using the bootstrap framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add margin to them  using CSS

```
.btn{
   margin: 0 5px;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. I just wrapped the links in `<p>` tags and it's fixed now. Any idea why that happened?

Comment: Probably there's spacing applied to the `p` tag in CSS as well. A perfectly valid solution as long as it works in your design!